# HaarCascade.detectMultiStage() always returning an empty tuple

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, face-detection, cascade-classifier

I'm trying to do mask detection on images and I'm trying to create bounding boxes around the faces. To do that I'm using the default haarcascade xml file, but no matter what I change the classifier never detects a face.

Something I read earlier said it might have something to do with the size? Honestly am just very lost, any help is appreciated.

```
haarcascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('../content/haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

im = cv2.imread('../content/285-with-mask.jpg')

im = cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
im=cv2.flip(im,1,1) 
    
rerect_size = cv2.resize(im, (im.shape[1] // rect_size, im.shape[0] // rect_size))
faces = haarcascade.detectMultiScale(rerect_size)
print(faces)
```

The image I'm running the classifier on:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JN8QW.png

Comment: The default haarcascade has been trained to detect visible faces. It won't detect partially occluded faces. You can train your own Haar classifier to detect masked/unmasked faces

Comment: May I asked why is this haarcascade.detectMultiScale(rerect_size[![enter image description here][1]][1])? Never seen before.

Comment: @toyotaSupra Sorry that was a weird copy paste error, I fixed it in the code above

Comment: @JeruLuke Do you think that I would be able to use an existing classifier that just detects heads?

Comment: @Joe Bierman -- you got a *logic* (or conceptual) problem here. haar cascades are binary. if it's trained on faces, it detects face or not a face (and it cant detect masked faces, occlusion) if you train it on masked faces, it detects masked faces or nothing, it wont detect the diff between a masked or unmasked face

Comment: @JoeBierman I don't think any classifier exists that detects head. As berak has stated you need to treat your problem as binary classification one if you proceed with Haar classifiers

Comment: @JoeBierman. This is only for face. But you cannot resizing. If you want to resizing you do like this `cv2.imshow('Image', rerect_size)` . Put his before `imshow` `haarcascade.detectMultiScale(im, 1.3, 5)`